# Android - Animate Image as ViewPager slides

Tags: android, android-viewpager, blur

**Question**: I want to blur an image as I slide from one page to another using a `ViewPager`.

**Scope**: I currently have an Activity which contains only a ViewPager. The ViewPager's adapter is a PagerAdapter which retrieves a specific Fragment. Within the Fragment there is an Image which I wish to blur/un-blur as the ViewPager moves on to the next page.

I have tried implementing the OnDragListener event but that doesn't get fired at all *as* I scroll from one page to another.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To detect the page change, you can extend the SimpleOnPageChangeListener. This works as an inner class in one of my activities (in my case, to play a sound):

```
    public class CustomViewPagerPageChangeListener extends CustomViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {
    int currentPage;

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);


        //swiperMediaPlayer.start();c
        _handler.removeCallbacks(_longPressed);//So page turn doesn't count as long click. Not applicable to you.
        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
            soundPool.play(pageSound, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);//Sub your blur code here
        }

    }  ...
```